# FCM notification is always showing

Tags: javascript, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm experiencing an issue with Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) push notifications in my web application. I've set up a service worker (firebase-messaging-sw.js) to handle notifications, and I want to prevent notifications from displaying under certain conditions. However, notifications are being displayed even when the conditions are met.

Here's the relevant code in my service worker:

```
// Scripts for firebase and firebase messaging
importScripts(
  "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-app-compat.js"
);
importScripts(
  "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-messaging-compat.js"
);
importScripts("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/localforage@1.9.0/dist/localforage.min.js");

// Initialize the Firebase app in the service worker by passing the generated config
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",`your text`
  appId: "",
  measurementId: "",
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

self.addEventListener("notificationclick", function (event) {
    event.notification.close();
    const urlToOpen = new URL("/", self.location.origin).href;

    const promiseChain = self.clients
        .matchAll({
            type: "window",
            includeUncontrolled: true,
        })
        .then((windowClients) => {
            let matchingClient = null;

            for (let i = 0; i < windowClients.length; i++) {
                const windowClient = windowClients[i];
                if (windowClient.url === urlToOpen) {
                    matchingClient = windowClient;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (matchingClient) {
                return matchingClient.focus();
            } else {
                return clients.openWindow(urlToOpen);
            }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
        });

    event.waitUntil(promiseChain);
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging()

messaging.onBackgroundMessage(async function (payload) {
  const notificationTitle = payload.notification.title;
  const notificationOptions = {
      body: payload.notification.body,
      icon: "./android-icon-192x192.png",
      requireInteraction: true,
    };
    const subscribedTables = await localforage.getItem("subscribedTables");
    console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background messagennn', payload, subscribedTables);
    const table = payload.data.table;
    if (subscribedTables && !subscribedTables[table]) {
        console.log("Not subscribed to table, ignoring notification");
        return;
    }
  self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
});
```

As you can see, there's a condition to check if the user is subscribed to a particular table before displaying the notification. However, even when this condition is met, the notification is still shown.

Could anyone provide insights or suggestions on how to prevent notifications from being displayed when this condition is met?

Comment: What type of message are you sending? Note that messages with a **notification** are handled by the system when the app is not active, so they never reach your app's `if (subscribedTables && !subscribedTables[table]) {` code. If you want full control of whether/how the message is displayed, send a message that has only a `data` property.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the message you're sending may have a `notification` property, and with a **notification** are handled by the system when the app is not active.

So this means the message never even reaches your app's `if (subscribedTables && !subscribedTables[table]) {` code, as the system displays it before that already.

If you want full control of whether/how the message is displayed, send a message that has only a `data` property. For more on this, see the Firebase documentation on [message types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages).